# How to make the legend with color more compact in a plot?

Tags: plotting, output-formatting, color, style, plot-themes

I have a plot as below:-

```
lg1 = {GraphicsRow[{Blue, "- Type A"}], GraphicsRow[{Orange, "- Type B"}]};
plot1 = ListPlot[{{{4, 1}, {3, 6}, {3, 4}}, {{4, 7}, {8, 5}, {2, 6}}}, PlotRange -> All];
Legended[plot1, lg1]
```

[image]

As you can see, the legend is very "loose". I want to to be more compact. In fact I can change `lg1` to `lg1 = Column@{"Blue - Type A", "Orange - Type B"}`, but then the color will become text as below:-

[image]

How can I keep the color and make it more compact? Many thanks!

Comment: Use an option from within ListPlot such as: `ListPlot[{{{4, 1}, {3, 6}, {3, 4}}, {{4, 7}, {8, 5}, {2, 6}}}, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> {"Type A", "Type B"}]`

Comment: Thanks for reply. But for this case, `Legended` is needed to be at the outer most layer. In my real case, there is a `show` between the `Legended` and the plots (there are several plots), and the legend needs to be dynamic as well. Thus the `Legended` cannot just be input as a plot option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GraphicsRow` is introducing lots of space.  If you're going to construct the legend manually, I suggest using `Row` instead, which gives a much more compact result:

```
lg1 = {Row[{Blue, "- Type A"}], Row[{Orange, "- Type B"}]};
plot1 = ListPlot[{{{4, 1}, {3, 6}, {3, 4}}, {{4, 7}, {8, 5}, {2, 6}}},
    PlotRange -> All];
Legended[plot1, lg1]
```

[image]

Also, the use of `Show` shouldn't necessarily be an issue for `Legended` or `PlotLegends`.  The dynamics might not either, but it may depend on what your specific usage is.

Answer (score 1):

```
Row[{ListPlot[{{{4, 1}, {3, 6}, {3, 4}}, {{4, 7}, {8, 5}, {2, 6}}}, 
   PlotRange -> All], 
  Grid[{{Blue, "- Type A"}, {Orange, "- Type B"}}]}]
```

[image: fig1]